# ANgular2 auto suggestion server call going in infinite loop

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Trying to implement auto suggestion with angular js

```
 $ npm install ng2-auto-complete --save
```

add map and packages to systemjs.config.js

```
 map['ng2-auto-complete'] = 'node_modules/ng2-auto-complete/dist';
 packages['ng2-auto-complete'] = { main: 'ng2-auto-complete.umd.js', ...]
```

Added the component

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'person',
    templateUrl: 'app/person/person.component.html'
})
personalData(personName: String): Observable<DepartmentModel[]>{
        let headers = new Headers();        
            if(personName!= undefined){

                headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
                headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
             return this.http.post(AppUtils.GET__MASTER_URL //return a list of department
             ,{personName:personName}
             ,{headers:headers})
                            .map(response => response.json())
                            .catch(this.handleError);
            }


    }
```

In person.component.html added the tag

```
<input auto-complete [(ngModel)]="myData"  [source]="personalData('test')" />
```

Its calling the service in loop.. browser got hanged.

used this one : https://github.com/ng2-ui/auto-complete

Answer (score 0):

Binding to a method like

```
[source]="personalData('test')"
```

causes change detection to call `personalData('test')` on every change detection cycle.

The usual way to work around that is to assign the result of `personalData('test')` to a property and bind to that property instead.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.personalData('test').subscribe(val => this.pd = val);
}
```

and then use

```
[source]="pd"
```

Comment: On each key press/up, I had to fetch data from the service. So I can't load all values initially.

Comment: You can use event bindings `(keypress)="personalData('test')"` to call the method, but don't use it in property bindings. Event bindings are executed when an event happens, property binding is executed every time change detection is run.

Comment: why that auto suggestion list is not showing ? any Help

Comment: Sorry, I don't know `ng2-auto-complete`

Comment: Does another autocomplete implemented in angular2 ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I haven't used auto-complete components myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

As per docs

```
source, array or string, required. data source for dropdown list
```

you are using a method to populate the source `personalData('test')`

So for every DOM updation service call will be made.

Comment: How to get it done? I need to get list from database

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the service call on `(ngModelChange)="search1($event)"` and call the service and fetch the data and bind it to `[source]="data"` where data has the data received from the last search.